Blow-in insulation over / near refrigerant lines
I have an AC unit outside the house with the refrigerant lines coming inside the house, up through the wall to the attic, across the attic and down through the ceiling to a 2nd floor closet that houses the furnace / air handler.  The attic is well vented (soffits with ridge vent), unconditioned space that contains all the ductwork for the 2nd floor.  The refrigerant lines are insulated with ~ 3/8" or 1/2" foam and run about 20" above the attic joists.
I am planning to blow in insulation to increase my depth to 24".  Are there any precautions I should take for the refrigerant lines since they would end up being covered?  Should I carve out a space around them so they won't be in contact with insulation?

Insulating is good, just make marker where the lies are buried
